# how to join two tables to get the company name from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to join "vt_invite" table to "vt_company" table.

- vt_invite table consist of basically a record of invitations of company who has invited other companies
- vt_company has info of the company.

After the query i want the result of all the data of vt_invite table and the company_name from the vt_company table WHERE vt_company_invites.from_company_id = 5 OR vt_company_invites.to_company_id = 5

For example

```
SELECT vt_company_invites.*, c1.name as from_name, c2.name as to_name 
FROM `vt_company_invites`  
LEFT JOIN vt_companies as c1 ON c1.id = vt_company_invites.from_company_id
LEFT JOIN vt_companies as c2 ON c2.id = vt_company_invites.to_company_id)
WHERE vt_company_invites.from_company_id = 5 OR vt_company_invites.to_company_id = 5
```

In this query the problem is that i am getting 2 company names (from_name , to_name). I only want one company_name where the company.id != 5

vt_invite

[image: vt_invite table picture]

vt_companies

[image: vt_companies table picture]

You will get the idea in this picture what i want, i only want the company_name where the company id != 5

[image: You will get the idea in this picture what i want, i only want the company_name where the company id != 5]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it next way:

```
SELECT 
    vt_company_invites.*, 
    IF(c1.id = 5, c1.name, c2.name) as company_name
FROM `vt_company_invites`  
LEFT JOIN vt_companies as c1 ON c1.id = vt_company_invites.from_company_id
LEFT JOIN vt_companies as c2 ON c2.id = vt_company_invites.to_company_id
WHERE 
    vt_company_invites.from_company_id = 5 OR 
    vt_company_invites.to_company_id = 5;
```

Comment: Thankyou @Salva, the answered helped me alot.
I just changed the IF condition to  IF(c1.id != 5, c1.name, c2.name) as company_name
And that gives me exactly what i wanted.
Thanks for the help